# Make object self-aware of its shape without explicit typing

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Consider the following two types:

```js
type CoolFunction = (c: CoolType) => any

type CoolType = {
    [key: string]: CoolType | CoolFunction
}

// can be nested many times
const example: CoolType = {
    foo: {
        bar: {},
        dog: (c) => c.foo
    },
    baz: (c) => c.foo.bar
}
```

Is it possible to construct a function that accepts a value of `CoolType` that will automatically provide the type of the argument passed into `CoolFunction`, without having to provide a type argument to the function?

```js
function doCoolStuff<T extends CoolType>(myCoolObj: T) {
    // recursively search for and call all CoolFunctions in myCoolObj with myCoolObj as param
}

doCoolStuff({
    someProperty: {
        foo: {},
    },
    somethingElse: {
        // the type of c should automatically be inferred to be the object we're currently creating
        test: (c) => c.someProperty.foo
    }
})
```

I'm assuming `CoolType` will have to accept some type parameters, and then pass those recursively inwards, but my attempts so far always ends in the type being `any` or `never`. An example:

```js
type CoolFunction<C extends CoolType<any, any>> = (c: C) => any;

// an attempt to provide the entire object shape,
// as well as the subtree of the property we're currently typing
type CoolType<
  Tree extends CoolType<any, any>,
  Subtree extends CoolType<any, any>
> = {
  [K in keyof Subtree]: Subtree[K] extends CoolFunction<Tree>
    ? CoolFunction<Tree>
    : Subtree[K] extends CoolType<any, any>
    ? CoolType<Tree, Subtree[K]>
    : never
};

function doCoolStuff<C extends CoolType<any, any>>(myCoolObj: C) {
  // recursively search for and call all CoolFunctions in myCoolObj with myCoolObj as param
}

doCoolStuff({
  foo: {
    bar: {}
  },
  // c: any
  baz: c => console.log(c.foo.bar)
});
```

Any pointers? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: `foo: "a",` doesn't appear to be a valid `CoolType` property?

Comment: @Bergi is right, your example type doesn't match your CoolType structure either `(c => foo `and `(c) ==foo.bar `is a syntax error

Comment: @Bergi Oops, sorry about that. I got my examples mixed up while drafting. I've updated the code so it hopefully is correct now.